# Angular 6 input type number and display 2 digits after comma

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I want to display input and when user enters a number: `20` I want `20,00` to be displayed. For greater numbers I want to see thousand separator like `11 200,00`.

```
<input type="number" (ngModelChange)="calculateSum()" (change)="calculateAmount(invoiceQuota)" [ngModel]="invoiceQuota.controls.grossAmount.value">
```

I tried to add:

```
[ngModel]="invoiceQuota.controls.grossAmount.value | number:'1.2-2'
```

but it does not work

I can't find solution to solve my problem.

Comment: number inputs don't accept spaces, and if I'm not mistaken, they are depending on the locale for the decimal separator (meaning you will either have a comma or a dot). If you want to format an input, the only way to do this is with a text input and [a mask](https://css-tricks.com/input-masking/).

Comment: In my region (Poland) the thousand separator is a space, and the decimal separator is a comma. So I just want my local format number to be displayed.

Comment: And in my country (France) we don't have a thousand separator and our decimal separator is a dot. As I said, rely on masks if you want to format an input.

Comment: Input type number does not support float values with commas
you should blur /focus event for changing values to decimal commas,
you also use PIPE for same in component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    import { Component, Input, NgZone, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

const PADDING = '00';
@Pipe({
    name: 'floatNumber'

})
export class FloatNumnberPipe implements PipeTransform {
    DECIMAL_SEPARATOR: string;
    THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR: string;

    constructor() {
    // TODO comes from configuration settings
        this.DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = '.';
        this.THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR = ',';
    }

    transform(value: number | string, fractionSize: number = 2): string {
        const ds = '.';
        const ts = ',';
        let [integer, fraction = ''] = (value || '').toString()
            .split(ds);

        fraction = fractionSize > 0
            ? ds + (fraction + PADDING).substring(0, fractionSize)
            : '';

        integer = integer.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ts);
        integer = integer ? integer : '0';
        return integer + fraction;
    }

    parse(value: string, fractionSize: number = 3): string {
        const ds = '.';
        const ts = ',';
        let [integer, fraction = ''] = (value || '').split(ds);

        integer = integer.replace(new RegExp(ts, 'g'), '');

        fraction = parseInt(fraction, 10) > 0 && fractionSize > 0
            ? ds + (fraction + PADDING).substring(0, fractionSize)
            : '';
        integer = integer ? integer : '0';
        return integer + fraction;
    }
}
 this way you can write float number PIPE and in component ,  if (typeof modelControlname === 'string') {


modelControlname=Math.round(Number(FloatNumnberPipe.prototype.parse(amount)) * 100) / 100);

  modelControlname=FloatNumnberPipe.prototype.transform(modelControlname.value);
```

Comment: If I enter `1000000` it returns `10,000.00`, but I want it to be `10 000,00`

Comment: ok you want spaces instead of comma , Just modify the Pipe it will take space instead of comma in trasform function , I already variable you can replace ds with space and . with ,