# Can't print value 0.00 on inputs, decimals get sliced

Tags: angular, typescript

**HTML**:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="sum" readonly="true">
```

**TS**:

```
sum: number;

const reset: number = 0.00;

sum = Number(reset).toFixed(2);
```

This 'works', I get the error

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

but it shows what I need.

The problem appears when I'm trying to reuse `sum`. If I do something like `sum = sum + 10`, I get `'0.0010'`.

Why does it get recognized as a string even if I'm casting `Number()`?

Comment: you need to cast your result to number like this `sum = +Number(reset).toFixed(2);` , `toFixed()` returns a string not a number

Comment: Didn't know that `+Number` was a thing, whats the purpose of that +? Btw it worked.

Comment: it's a shorthand for `parseInt()` & `parseFloat()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 input type number and display 2 digits after comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51306811/angular-6-input-type-number-and-display-2-digits-after-comma) - I'm assuming you're using Angular here because of the `[(ngModel)]`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toFixed()` will return you a `string` and not a `Number` and that's why you get the error, you need to cast the result to a `number` with either of the following

Shorthand **+** [unary plus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewkkxkwb.aspx)

```
sum = +Number(reset).toFixed(2);
```

**parseFloat()**

```
sum = parseFloat(Number(reset).toFixed(2));
```